# How to insert the Element in an Array that contains a Substring, into another array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I Have an Array as below

```
headers = Array["RATE THIS MOVIE", "SHOWTIMES FOR TODAY, FEB 25", "MOVIE INFO", "PHOTOS", "CAST", "CRITIC REVIEWS", "USER REVIEWS"]
```

Now I want to check if its elements contain a Substring "SHOWTIMES"

if Yes, then I want it to add that element into another array

```
new_header= ["SHOWTIMES FOR TODAY, FEB 25", ....]
```

I tried the below, but it gives me the error message

```
# undefined local variable or method `s` for #<MovieDetails:0x007f939b956420> (NameError)

if ( headers.any? { |s| s.include?('SHOWTIMES') }  )
  headers.push('s')
end
```

please Advice

Comment: Your post says that you're working with an array of strings, but the error message suggests that you're calling method `s` on an object of class `MovieDetails`. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted the Error Message as is....the Error message is undefined local variable. Please ignore the other details in the error message.

Comment: It's actually the details that make an error message useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`.

```
new_header = headers.grep(/SHOWTIMES/)
```

Comment: Always the simplest answers! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `.select` and `.match`

```
new_headers = headers.select { |s| s.match(/SHOWTIMES/) }
     => ["SHOWTIMES FOR TODAY, FEB 25"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( headers.any? { |s| s.include?('SHOWTIMES') }  )
  new_header.push('s')
end
```

The reason why this code doesn't work, is that `s` is a variable that only exists inside the block `{ |s| s.include?('SHOWTIMES') }`

As soon as you are outside that block - `s` disappears.
So you have to do something that uses `s` - while it still exists.

There are several ways of doing that.

First - you could try doing it inside of a block... eg:

```
headers.each { |s| 
    if s.include?('SHOWTIMES') 
      new_header.push(s)
    end
}
```

But a better way is to use the matching methods as explained in the other comments:

```
# select will pick out the ones that match your criteria
new_header = headers.select{|s| s.include?('SHOWTIMES') }

# match is also a powerful way of doing this if what you want to match 
# is more complicated (google "ruby regex")
new_header = headers.select{|s| s.match?(/SHOWTIMES/) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Detailed explanation, This helped solve the problem. :)